# Spanner Emulator information_schema.columns missing COLUMN_DEFAULT column

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Finally Spanner emulator is out and it is great for local development. I just want to report this issue that information_schema.columns table missing COLUMN_DEFAULT column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback. I am happy to hear you are having a good experience using the emulator.

We are tracking this feature request and hope to add it within the next few releases.